# Ideals of quotient ring of a principal ideal domain are also principal ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R$ be a PID. I have to show that every ideal of a quotient ring of $R$ is a principal ideal. I am able to visualize this problem by taking $R=Z$. I took ideal $(20)$ of $Z$ for example. Then I got quotient ring as:
$R/(20)=\{(20),1+(20),2+(20),.......,19+(20)\}$.
When I consider an ideal of this quotient ring e.g. $\{(20),2+(20),4+(20),.....,18+(20)\}$,

I can see that this ideal is  generated by a single element of the ideal i.e. $2+(20)$. Thus it is a principal ideal. Similar thing can be said about other ideals of the quotient ring. But when it comes to formal proof of this, I do not have a clue as to how to do that. Please suggest.

Comment: Use the correspondence $\{\text{ideal }J\text{ of }R/I\}$ with $\{\text{ideal }J\supseteq I\text{ of }R\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

Use that ideals in a quotient ring $R/I$ correspond bijectively to ideals $J$ of $R$ that contain $I$ by the correspondance $J\longmapsto J/I$. In  terms of P.I.D., this means that a generator of the ideal $J$ will divide the generators of $I$.